# Best book on the theory of Standard Model of particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model, elementary-particles

I am interested to learn a concise and complete theoretical overview of the currently accepted Standard Model of particle physics. Standard Model books that I have encountered so far (like Bjorken and Drell if I recall correctly?) contain a lot of historical (and maybe outdated) stuff, like parton models, some weird form factors etc. So I wonder if there exists a modern exposition of just the currently up to date theory (with references to relevant experiments, but no attempt to delve deeper into them within the book itself)?

Comment: Can we assume a background in QFT already (i.e. at least the level of Peskin and Schroeder)?

Comment: @JamalS Yes, I'd prefer a book that assumes QFT for the sake of being short and concise.